# how to move backup from Nokia 808 to Lumia 1020

Tags: whatsapp, backup, nokia-lumia-1020

I have a Nokia 808. Whatsapp informed that their app will not be available on Symbian OS after 31-12-2017. Lumia 1020 has no memory card no any other phone directory, So how can i move WhatsApp backup to Lumia 1020.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try copying the Whatsapp folder from old phone to new phone?

Comment: @RamRaj How would you suggest doing that on a phone without an SD card?

Comment: By connecting phone to pc via usb cable and copying that folder onto phone.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the data Whatsapp folder to this location *Phone/Whatsapp* in your Lumia 1020.

You can do this connecting your phone to a PC or compressing and sending the folder via Internet. You can use softwares like 8zip for compression. However connecting to a PC is an easy option.